# Angular Directive Controller best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

Which one is the best way to define directive controller. I referred some site they explained Option1.

Option 1:

```
angular.module('app')directive('AppHeader', AppHeader);

function AppHeader() {
  var headerDirective = {
     restrict: 'E',
     templateUrl: 'header.html',
     link: linkFunc, 
     controllerAs: 'vm',
     controller: NavCtrl
   };
   return headerDirective;

   function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
      /* */
   }
}

NavCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Service'];
function NavCtrl($scope, Service) {
    var vm = this;
    /* Controller actions */
}
```

In the above code Controller separated from the directive function block.

Option 2:

```
 angular.module('app').directive('AppHeader', AppHeader);

 function AppHeader() 
 {
     var headerDirective = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'header.html',
        link: linkFunc, 
        controllerAs: 'vm',                
        controller: NavCtrl
      };

     return headerDirective;

     function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
        /* */
     }
     NavCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Service'];
     function NavCtrl($scope, Service) {
        var vm = this;
        /* Controller actions */
     }
}
```

In the above code Controller added in directive function block.

So which one is best practice to create and define the Directive controller and Why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Option 2, you have scoped the function to level where you are actually using.

In Option 1, you have scoped the function a level higher, There is no need for it to be a level above as it will not be reused.

I feel Option 2 makes the function correctly scoped.

Further you might want to enclose entire Option 2 code in IIFE (immediately invoked function expression)

```
(function(){
   //Your code here

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go with option 1 because.

The directive's controller should be outside the directive's closure. This way you eliminate possible issues where the injection gets created as unreachable code after a return.

You should read John Papa's [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#directives), he explains all kind of things about code styling in angular.